# How to take id of model X from DetailView and add it to the CreateView of model Y?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Let's say I have an app with two models, model Car and model Tire, each one has a form and Car is associated with Tire via ForeignKey.

```
#models.py
class Car(models.Model):
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Car")
    car_make = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Make")

class Tire(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", related_name="Car")
    tire_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Car")
    tire_make = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Make")
```

When user creates Car with an example form below, they are redirected to a DetailView of a Car.

```
#forms.py
class CarCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = (
        'car_name',
        'car_make'
        )
```

On the DetailView page there is a button "Add Tire", by clicking on it users are transferred to the TireCreateView (which has a form).

```
#forms.py
class TireCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tire
        fields = (
        'car',
        'tire_name',
        'tire_make'
        )
```

But problem is that in this view user has to choose from many Cars (which are already in DB) and after that enter Tire details. I want to achieve following process:

1. User visits CarDetailView
2. User clicks "Add Tire" button
3. Form shows only tire_name and tire_make fields
4. User fills those fields and submits the form
5. **Tire details are added to the Car from Step 1**

How can I define the car part in a TireCreateForm and in TireCreateView to automatically get the Car ID to which user wants Tire added?

**EDIT:**

```
#car_detail.html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="btn-group pull-right m-t-15">

<div class="button-list">

<a href="{% url 'ap:tire-create' car.id%}" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light">
<span class="btn-label">
<i class="ti-flag"></i>
</span> Add Tire</a>    

</div>    
</div>


#views.py
class CarDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'car_detail.html'
    queryset = Car.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Car, id=id_)

class TireCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'tire_create.html'
    form_class = TireForm
    queryset = Tire.objects.all()

    def get_initial(self):
            return dict(car=self.kwargs.get("id"))

    def form_valid(self, form):

        #Meta information
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_date = timezone.now()

        return super().form_valid()

#urls.py    
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/<int:id>', TireCreateView.as_view(), name="tire-create"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on add tire button, send the pk id of car to create view through url

**car_detail.html**

`<a href="{% url 'app_name:add_tires' car.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add Tire</a>`

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_tires/<pk:uuid>', views.TireCreateView.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**
override the `get_initial` method to send initial values to your form

```
class CreateTireView(CreateView)
  # your CreateTireView
  #####
  def get_initial(self):
    """Return the initial data to use for forms on this view."""
    return dict(car=self.kwargs.get("pk")
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! I applied your solution but when submitting the form got the error: name 'car' is not defined. Could you please provide little bit more information for implementing your solution?

Comment: post your `CreateView` and car detail html page, You are getting that error because you object_name must be something else in  car_detail_view.html

Comment: Have you defined `context_object_name` in you CarDetailView? if you have than `{% url 'ap:tire-create' whatever_your_context_object_name.id%}`
Else for more detail also post you `CarDetailView`

Comment: I do not have context_object_name defined but have provided the CarDetailView as well in my question

Comment: Ok then use `{% url 'ap:tire-create' object.id %}`

Answer (score 0):

I think i fixed it by modifying views.py:

## views.py

```
class TireCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'tire_create.html'
    form_class = TireForm
    queryset = Tire.objects.all()
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        car = get_object_or_404(Car, id=self.kwargs.get("id"))  
        form.instance.car = car

        #Meta information
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_date = timezone.now()

        return super().form_valid()
```